# Need to forward folder of 1000 pages

Tags: .htaccess, forward

I am given the task of forwarding a folder of hundreds of URLs to a new folder name. The URL: "http://domain.com/old/1_of_1000_pages" to http://domain.com/new/1_of_1000_pages".

What is the best way to do this? Use .htaccess? I shouldn't write all of them individually, right? There might be 1,000. Is there a way to just forward everything going to /old/ to /new/ while still reaching the correct /1_of_1000_pages ?

I'm a web designer, but I'm not that familiar with .htaccess code yet!

Thank you ahead of time!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple generic `RedirectMatch` rule to handle all URLs in your website root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/old/(.*)$ /new/$1
```